# UITextFields Overlapping After UITableView Scroll

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITableView with UITextFields to make a form. It looks great - EXCEPT when you scroll new UITextFields are placed on top of the old ones... I cant figure out why! I know that when the cell is reused (i.e. dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns non-nil), the cell is returned with the existing UITextField. I have found a solution where to maintain the uniqueness of the tags, it'll be better to remove any previous UITextField. But I dont want to do that. At the end when this form is submitted, I want to take all the values from the textfields (cant do that if I remove them)..

Here is the code. Any help is appreciated!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(155, 15, 130, 30)];
playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Unique ID Sample";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
}

else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Common Name";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Scientific Name";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 3) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"03/25/1992";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 4) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Male";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
} 

else if ([indexPath row] == 5) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"03/01/2012";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 6) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Huntington, WV";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 7) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Huntington, WV";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 8) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Marshall University";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
} 
else if ([indexPath row] == 9) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Sub Straight";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 10) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Any Light";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 11) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Temperature";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 12) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"A Lot";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
} 

else if ([indexPath row] == 13) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"All Types";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 14) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Schedule";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 15) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"MM/DD/YYYY";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 16) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Ate Someone";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
} 

else if ([indexPath row] == 17) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"MM/DD/YYYY";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 18) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"The Morgue";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 19) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"MM/DD/YYYY";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

else if ([indexPath row] == 20) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"MM/DD/YYYY";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
} 

else if ([indexPath row] == 21) {
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"To/ From";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}    

playerTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
playerTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
playerTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
playerTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
playerTextField.tag = 0;

playerTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever; // no clear 'x' button to the right
[playerTextField setEnabled: YES];

    [cell addSubview:playerTextField];

[playerTextField release];

cell.textLabel.text = [self.options objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;    
}
```

Comment: Why you are added same property this much of times ?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to create a custom `UITableViewCell`. This will allow you to create an `ivar` with a `UITextField` that you can access directly. This way, when the cell get dequeued and reused, you can simply set when you need it.  Be sure to override `prepareForReuse:` in your cell subclass and reset all of the properties on your added components.

Another thing that may help you out with your code above is the use of a `typedef enum` instead of using integers to determine what type of cell it is:

```
typedef enum{
    PlayerFieldId = 0,
    PlayerFieldName,
    PlayerFieldGender
} PlayerFields
```

Then in either your custom cell, you can set the type of cell it is by the enum above and a switch statement:

```
switch(type){
case PlayerFieldId:
    playerTextField.placeholder = @"Unique ID Sample";
    playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
    break;
    /* other fields here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UITableViewCell and have it have a UITextField property that you just set for every cell instead of adding a new one constantly if you don't want to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following statement to create cell instance.

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

```
for (UITextView *txtView in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    if ([txtView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
    {
        [txtView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
```